# Is there a way in Java to call a different hashCode() for an interface representation of an object

Tags: java, interface

I've been dealing with a domain issue where I have classes that implement a common interface and I want to be able to get hashes from these objects differently depending on if the object is accessed as an interface or as a concrete class instance. Basically what I want is the following:

```
public class A implements Bar{
  @Override
  public int hashCode(){ return 1;}

  @Override
  public int Bar.hashCode(){ return 123;}
}
public class B implements Bar{
  @Override
  public int hashCode(){ return 1;}

  @Override
  public int Bar.hashCode(){ return 123;}
}
public class C implements Bar{
  @Override
  public int hashCode(){ return 1;}

  @Override
  public int Bar.hashCode(){ return 123;}
}

Bar interfaceObject = new A();
interfaceObject.hashCode(); //return 123

Bar aObject = new A();
aObject.hashCode();// return 1
```

As far as I know there isn't a way to do this, and I can think of lots of reasons why this could cause issues, but I wanted to ask those smarter than I if they had any nice ways of doing this outside of making the interface have a function like `public int getCustomHashCodeForJustThisInterface()`. I like being able to use these objects in hashMaps without having to jump through hoops, but with their current implementation of hashCode they would break, since these objects can have multiple views of their identity depending on how they are used, and I don't want to change their base implementation of hashCode;

Comment: Except for the name, there is no difference between the two invocation of `hashCode()`.

Comment: _depending on if the object is accessed as an interface or as a concrete class instance._ That is impossible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that, because Java does not support non-polymorphic *instance* methods (static methods are not polymorphic, as the previous answer showed).
What you can do is to make your classes **not** directly implement `Bar`, but another interface (e.g. `BarProvider`) with a `toBar()` or `getBar()` method, which returns a custom object of type `Bar`, which behaves as you want.

```
public class A implements BarProvider{
  @Override
  public int hashCode(){ return 1;}

  @Override
  public Bar toBar() {
    return new Bar() {
        @Override
        public int hashCode() { return 123; }
    };
  }
}

A aObject = new A();
interfaceObject.hashCode(); //return 1;
Bar interfaceObject = aObject.toBar();
interfaceObject.hashCode(); // return 123
```

Several improvements are possible, such as having the `Bar` object stored as a final field (to avoid multiple initializations), and having a reverse reference that allows you to get back from the `Bar` to its `BarProvider`.

---

Another possibility is to use an external provider, that makes your computations

```
public class A implements Bar{
  @Override
  public int hashCode(){ return 1;}
}

public final class BarHasher implements Hasher<Bar> }
  @Override
  public int hashFor(Bar object) { return 123; }
}

A aObject = new A();
interfaceObject.hashCode(); //return 1;
BarHasher.hashFor(aObject); // return 123
```

or a static method that calls some other method

```
public class A implements Bar{
  @Override
  public int hashCode(){ return 1;}

  @Override
  public int hashAsBar() { return 123; }
}

public interface BarHasher implements Hasher<Bar> {
  @Override
  public int hashFor(Bar object) { return object.hashAsBar(); }
}

A aObject = new A();
interfaceObject.hashCode(); //return 1;
BarHasher.hashFor(aObject); // return 123
```

---

In case you don't know it, what you're trying to do is possible (and it's the default behavior) in C++ (you must declare methods as `virtual` to have the same behavior as Java) and in C# (but you will have a warning, unless you use the modifier [`new`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx) on the overriding method)

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do this that I know of.

---

Here's something you can do that you may not have known of (I'm **not** suggesting this is a good idea):

```
package com.sandbox;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Sandbox {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        A.speak();
        B.speak();

        A a = new A();
        a.speak(); //my ide rightly gives a warning here. static function accessed through instance

        A b = new B();
        b.speak(); //my ide rightly gives a warning here. static function accessed through instance
    }

    public static class A {
        public static void speak() {
            System.out.println("A");
        }
    }

    public static class B extends A {
        public static void speak() {
            System.out.println("B");
        }
    }

}
```

This will print:

```
A
B
A
A
```

Just to reiterate: **This is NOT a good idea**.  I'm just letting you know for educational purposes.

Comment: If you want to invoke different instance methods, rather than static ones, then that's a simple extension - define the methods as private methods in each class, then have the pseudo-overloaded static methods simply invoke them.

Comment: The issue here is that the methods are static, and so they don't have a reference to the object you meant to invoke them on. Even if the example is simple, I guess Zipper would like the methods to return some non-hardcoded value, depending on the state of the object the method is invoked on.

Comment: @GiulioFranco yep, like I said I just showed it for educational purposes, not to directly help with his problem.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to invoke different methods based on the *declared* type of a variable. That's called overriding, and here's an example of it:

```
public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
        Integer v1 = 12;
        Number v2 = v1;

        System.out.println(v1.hashCode() + " -> " + new KeyWrapper(v1).hashCode());
        System.out.println(v2.hashCode() + " -> " + new KeyWrapper(v2).hashCode());
    }

    private static class KeyWrapper {
        private Object obj;
        private int hash;

        public KeyWrapper(Integer v) {
            this.hash = v.hashCode() * 3;
        }

        public KeyWrapper(Number v) {
            this.hash = v.hashCode() * 5;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

When you run this, you get the following output:

```
12 -> 36
12 -> 60
```

Why this is a bad idea is that you can't implement `equals()` in in a way that preserves its contract (which is that two equal objects must have equal hashcodes). At compile-time you have information about how the values are *referenced*, but at runtime you only know what they *are*.

That said, if you want to use different hashcode calculations for objects that do implement an interface, versus those that don't, you can write a `KeyWrapper` that uses `instanceof`.

```
public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
        Integer v1 = 12;
        String v2 = "foo";

        System.out.println(v1.hashCode() + " -> " + new KeyWrapper(v1).hashCode());
        System.out.println(v2.hashCode() + " -> " + new KeyWrapper(v2).hashCode());
    }

    private static class KeyWrapper {
        private Object wrapped;

        public KeyWrapper(Object obj) {
            this.wrapped = obj;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            return wrapped.equals(obj);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return (wrapped instanceof Number) ? wrapped.hashCode() * 3 : wrapped.hashCode() * 5;
        }   
    }
}
```

This, of course, *doesn't* care about the declared type of the variable, only its actual type.